# Export room database to json file

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

Is it possible to export all room database with all tables, entries to json file? I saw some [example](https://advancedweb.hu/2015/01/06/efficient-sqlite-backup-on-android/) done with SQLite, but how about Room database?

Answer (score 5):

You can pass your Room entity objects to a JSON generator as you see fit. If you wish to retrieve a bunch of the entities and write them to JSON, you can do so.

In other words, you can write the data from `Dog` and `Cat` objects to JSON, using a JSON generator. Where the `Dog` and `Cat` objects come from — Room, Retrofit, Realm, etc. — does not matter.

Implementing the scope of the export ("all room database with all tables, entries") is up to you.

Comment: and how about many to many database with foreign keys and join tables?

Comment: @kosas: At the level of `Dog` and `Cat` POJOs, and at the level of JSON, there are no such things as foreign keys and join tables. How you choose to model those in the JSON are up to you, and Room is not involved much in that modeling approach.

Comment: Thank you for help!

Answer (score 3):

It will be helpful if you understand how to export a table from Room Database to JSON. Let see how to do it.

> Step 1: Create **Model** for Room Database

```
    @Entity(tableName = "students")
    public class Student{
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        private int id;
        @ColumnInfo(name = "std_name")
        private String name;
        public Student(int id, String name){
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
        @Ignore
        public Student(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
     }
```

> Step 2: Create **Data Access Object(DAO)** for Room Database

```
@Dao
public interface StudentDAO {
    @Query("select * from students")
    List<Student> getStudents();

    @Insert
    public void insert(Student student);

    // Other CRUD methods
    // ..........
}
```

> Step 3: Now Create **Room Database**

```
@Database(entities = { Student.class }, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class StudentDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static final String DB_NAME ="StudentDb";
    private static StudentDatabase stdInstance;
    public abstract StudentDAO stdDAO();    

    public synchronized static StudentDatabase getInstance(final Context context) {
        if (stdInstance == null) {
            stdInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, StudentDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
                                        .allowMainThreadQueries().build();
        }
        return stdInstance;
    }
}
```

> Step 4: Export **Student table** from Room Database as JSON

```
// Create reference variables in your Activity
private List<Student> stdList;
private StudentDatabase stdDatabase;

private void exportJSON(){
    Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {
           // stdDatabase.stdDAO().getStudents();
        }
    }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    stdList = stdDatabase.stdDAO().getStudents();
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Student>>(){}.getType();
                    String stdJson = gson.toJson(stdList, type);

                    // Call function to write file to external directory
                    writeToStorage(getApplicationContext(), "StudnetJson", stdJson)
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    // Show error message
                }
            });
    }

//Create a Method in your Activity
public void writeToStorage(Context mContext, String fileName, String jsonContent){      
    File file = new File(mContext.getFilesDir(),"exportStudentJson");
    if(!file.exists()){
        file.mkdir();
    }
    try{
        File mFile = new File(file, fileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(mFile);
        writer.append(jsonContent);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Even if you don't understand please let me write comments.

Note: In future I'll create a GitHub project for this issue. Thanks