# Basic database with Json export

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin, data-entry

1. I need to enter lots of data to my android application before it published.
   I need an application offline that like an excell table and after i entered my data it should give me json list file.
   (Please don't say csv to json.)
2. And secondly is there somebody  who entered huge data into an application. How can i do it alternativly?

Thanks

I tried rowy but it is not working offline.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Room for data to JSON needs: [Export room database to json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915638/export-room-database-to-json-file)

You can also preload data to Room: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate

Comment: Thans for help. But i decided to use rowy. I just wanted an offline version of rowy bu there is  not. it exports as json